# php ReflectionClass

Tags: php, reflection, class

hey all i want to use ReflectionClass to load some classes 
defined in my xml file

but i am getting an error

```
Error while register class :Class ReportErrorHandler does not exist
```

i will not get this error when i will use

```
require_once( 'handlers/system/ReportErrorHandler.php' );
```

but i dont want to require_once the class ,this is why i am using reflection
and in my xml file i am writing only the class name 
with no full path ,so i cant dynamically 'require_once'

here is my code

```
 public function init(){
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'server.xml' );

$handlers = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "handler" );
foreach( $handlers as $handler ) {
  $this->register($handler->nodeValue);
}
}

public function register(&$name) {
try{
  $intercafe = new ReflectionClass('Handler');

  $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($name);

  if(!$reflectionClass->isSubclassOf($intercafe)){
    //LOG ERROR
    error_log("Init-> Error ," + name + " is not a subclass of [net/Handler]");

    throw new InvalidArgumentException();
  }

  error_log("register: " . $reflectionClass);

  $handler  = $reflectionClass->newInstance();
  $type = $handler->getType();

  //LOG DEBUG
  syslog(LOG_DEBUG ,"Registering handler = " . $name . " TYPE = " . $type);

  $key = $type << 32;

  $this->table[$key] = $reflectionClass;
}catch(Exception $ee){
  error_log("Error while register class :" . $ee->getMessage());
}
}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <server>
     <server-version>0.1</server-version>

     <handlers>
       <handler>AuthenticateHandler</handler>
       <handler>ReportErrorHandler</handler>

       <handler>DisconnectedHandler</handler>
       <handler>NoSuchRequestHandler</handler>
     </handlers>
  </server>
```

Answer (score 3):

> but i dont want to require_once the
>   class ,this is why i am using
>   reflection

Even reflection needs to know what it is that it's supposed to be reflecting.
Why don't you want to include/require the class definition?

Comment: cause , in my xml there is only a class file to load ,
and i was thinking to my self that this is weird to put the full path in the xml , and use reflection with the parsed class name only 
and requirre_once with the full path , 
i mean in java i don't need to import the class to reflect 
its just a class ,its not an instance

Comment: this is what i have to do . use full path for require_once and use className for reflection ?

Comment: That's where setting up an autoloader (as Gordon has indicated) will automatically include/require the class file for you... but even an autoloader still needs to know where to look to find the file if it isn't in the include path

Comment: autoload directory , what happens when i have many classes in different directories?

Comment: @shay Typically, most people use a naming convention for their classes that allows them to resolve a directory path from the class name.... e.g. class PHPExcel_Worksheet_Row resolves to PHPExcel/Worksheet/Row.php

Answer (score 2):

Setup [Autoloading](http://www.rafaeldohms.com.br/2009/06/03/spl-a-hidden-gem/en/) with

- [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) — Register given function as `__autoload()` implementation

Comment: this is what i get ,   
Error while register class :Function 'ReportErrorHandler' not found (function 'ReportErrorHandler' not found or invalid function name)

Comment: @shay Like @Mark already said, you have to include the files. The autoloader can do this for you automatically, so you dont have to write include statements, but you have to set it up so it can find your classes. It doesnt matter how it is done in Java. PHP aint Java.

Answer (score 0):

this is what is did to solve my problem 
i separate the full path for require_once

```
public function register(&$name) {
try{
  $intercafe = new ReflectionClass('Handler');

  $fullPath = $name;
  $className = $name;

  $index = strrpos($name , "/");
  if($index != False){
    $className = substr($name ,$index + 1);
  }

  $requirePath = 'handlers/' . $fullPath . '.php';
  require_once ( $requirePath );
  $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($className);

  if(!$reflectionClass->isSubclassOf($intercafe)){
    //LOG ERROR
    error_log("Init-> Error ," + name + " is not a subclass of [net/Handler]");

    throw new InvalidArgumentException();
  }

  $handler  = $reflectionClass->newInstance();
  $type = $handler->getType();

  //LOG DEBUG
  syslog(LOG_DEBUG ,"Registering handler = " . $name . " TYPE = " . $type);

  $key = $type << 32;

  $this->table[$key] = $reflectionClass;
}catch(Exception $ee){
  error_log("Error while register class :" . $ee->getMessage());
}
```

}